# Implement Follow Unfollow In Rails With Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am new to Ruby on Rails. Now going to implement a user "follow/unfollow" feature to a project. It can be implemented using raw rails. But I prefer to implement it with a gem. Is there any gem to implement user follow/unfollow in rails?

Answer (score 1):

Although in SO you can not ask like this type of questions off topic because of

> questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software
>   library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack
>   Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.
>   Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve
>   it.

. But

As a new on ROR .You might  be search this on [ruby toolbox](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com) Or [Github](http://github.com) Or [RubyGems](http://rubygems.org)

But for only `follow unfollow` as like `acts_as_votable` you can use the below gem

[acts_as_follower](https://github.com/tcocca/acts_as_follower)

Or if you want all like follow, like, mention use

[socialization](https://github.com/cmer/socialization) gem

Answer (score 0):

You could use this gem: [acts_as_follower](https://github.com/tcocca/acts_as_follower)

Answer (score -1):

There is gem present for this i.e [acts_as_follower](https://github.com/tcocca/acts_as_follower)

Sample of how to use acts_as_follower with rails3 see 
[Sample Application](https://gist.github.com/tcocca/863091)